# PHP MYSQL Skip result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
product_id   price   product_special_id   priority
    1          50            1              1
    1          30            2              2                   
    1          70            3              1
    2          50            1              1
   ...         ...          ...            ...
```

How can i select product_id from table where price is lower than 40 and skipping 1 because have more prices with same priority?

Comment: what's skipping one?

Comment: you mean: `select product_id from table where price < 40 group by priority` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear, but you can group by **product_id** and **priority** and discard those elements that have more than one price for the same priority like this:

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    priority,
    MAX(price) AS price
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    price <= 40
GROUP BY
    product_id, priority
HAVING
    COUNT(price) < 2
```

Since you only have into accounts groups with only one price, the aggregation method MAX() will return just that price.